# PyCharm: How to change menu hot-tracking background color?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2023.1, enabling IntelliJ Light scheme, and quickly find a small problem.

The menu hot-tracking background is in deep blue color, and it makes some UI element vague, like this:

[image]

The three "dots" are nearly invisible. I searched through *Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → General*, still no luck.

Changing "Selection background" only affects that from code editing area. As show below:

[image]

Then is it possible to customize that hot-tracking background color?

BTW: Back in PyCharm 2020.2, it was not "three dots" but a "triangle arrow", which stood out and did not cause visual problem.

[image: PyCharm 2020.2 popout menu]

Comment: Note: To see the pixel-clear image of my screen shot, you may need to right click the image, execute "Open image in new tab". The web-browser's in-web rendering of the image may present a vague preview.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to customize the hot-tracking background color in PyCharm.

Here's how:

1.Go to Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → General.

2.Click on the "Editor" tab.

3.Scroll down to the "Selection background" option and click on the color box next to it.

4.Choose your preferred color for the hot-tracking background and click "OK" to save the changes.

5.Restart PyCharm to see the new color in action.
Note: Make sure to select a color that provides enough contrast against the UI elements to avoid any visibility issues.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve. Selection Background affects only code editing area.